# Mvc3 choose DisplayFor-Template by DataType-Annotiation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to choose the DisplayFor-Template by the DataType Annotiation

So in my Model I have:

```
[DataType("Foo")]
public String Bar {get;set;}
```

and now I do not want to use the standard string DisplayFor, I want to use a special DisplayFor for "Foo"

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's the problem here. Doesn't [DisplayName("Foo")] cut it?

Comment: No, I do not want to Dislpay "Foo", I wont that @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.bar) points to the display helper for "Foo" and not to the display helper for string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control the template that MVC chooses, you need to use the [UIHint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.aspx) attribute.